# Is sound system in linux layered system as OSI model?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I'm new with linux and especially with sound system. I've read many articles about this subject but I'm still confused. I know that Alsa provides audio functionality to the rest of the system. This mean that Alsa is lowest "layer" on sound system (after hardware itself). I also know that ALSA by itself can only handle one application at a time. So here are my questions:
1)Is PulseAudio a bridge to provide usage of Alsa for multiple apps?
2)Are Gstreamer, Phonon and Xine same bridge programs as PulseAudio?
3)Is Alsa converting analog signal into digital signal?

My questions may seem stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSI model isn't really a good fit to ALSA, as it really only provides layer 1.

PulseAudio is an audio server and is the single client of a ALSA device interface. It provides something analogous to Layer 7 of the OSI model to applications. It mixes the audio output streams from each client application connection down to a single stream for output.  It provides an alsa-compatible interface to audio client software (e.g. GStreamer and Xine) which acts as a proxy and connects to the audio server.

Analogue to digital (and digital to analogue) conversion takes place in hardware in what is referred to, rather confusingly, as a CoDec.

Comment: and one more question please... Does every sound that goes into sound card goes through ALSA and then PulseAudio? and can someone use oss instead of alsa?

Comment: It's a case of either ALSA or OSS - and OSS is massively obsolete.